# How to remove a specific recipient from all e-mail templates in a directory on my desktop?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a directory folder (folder on desktop) of outlook messages `(.msg)` that I use as templates for crafting e-mails.

There may be 500 e-mails in this folder. I need to delete a specific e-mail address from each of these emails sometimes after every month.

```
Sub test()

Dim m As MailItem 'object/mail item iterator
Dim recip As Recipient 'object to represent recipient(s)
Dim email As Long

Set Remove = m.Remove

email = InputBox("Please enter the e-mail address you wish to remove")
answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this e-mail?", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Delete?")
If answer = vbYes Then

For Each m In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
If m.Class = olMail Then
Set Remove = m.Recipients.Remove(email)

End If

m.Save
End If

Next

End Sub
```

How do I do it with VBA?

If an e-mail has johndoe@gmail.com, I expect that e-mail to be deleted after i run this code in all TO,CC,BCC etc.

Comment: Where are you running the code from? Outlook or Excel?

Comment: I am running the code from Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try this*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Path As String
        Path = "C:\Temp"

    Dim msgFile As String
        msgFile = Dir(Path & "\*.msg")

    Dim msg As Object
    Do While Len(msgFile) > 0
        Set msg = Application.Session.OpenSharedItem(Path & "\" & msgFile)
        Debug.Print msg.Subject

            GetSMTPAddress msg

        msgFile = Dir
    Loop

    Set msg = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub GetSMTPAddress(Mail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor

    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

    Dim i As Long
    For i = Mail.Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
        DoEvents
        Set pa = Mail.Recipients(i).PropertyAccessor

        If LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)) = _
           LCase("0m3r@Email.com") Then
                Mail.Recipients.Remove (i)
                Debug.Print pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
                Mail.Save
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

*Make sure to update email address `0m3r@Email.com` and folder path `Path = "C:\Temp"`*

Comment: You are the BOSS. Thank you. I added a "On Error Resume Next on top of your If statement. Seems like the "Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS as String" line will return an error if some e-mails are not within Microsoft Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Application.Session.OpenSharedItem` for each MSG file, remove the recipient, call `MailItem.Save`.